# Why do we need override components in angular 2 testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a confusion regarding the usage of override component while testing.
In the code below I have mocked a service called `HomeModel`.

**With overrideComponent**

```
TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
        imports: [CoreModule],
        declarations: [HomeComponent],
        providers: [
            {provide: Router, useValue: router}
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .overrideComponent(HomeComponent, {        
        set: {
            providers: [
                {provide: HomeModel, useClass: MockHomeModel}
            ],
        }
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

**Without overrideComponent**

```
TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
        imports: [CoreModule],
        declarations: [HomeComponent],
        providers: [
            {provide: Router, useValue: router},
            {provide: HomeModel, useClass: MockHomeModel}
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Can't we just specify `useClass` in `providers` instead of overriding the component? In my case, it works only if I override. The latter does not work.

What is the main use of `overrideComponent` in testing?

Comment: `does not work` fits literally everything. What exactly does not work?

Comment: @smnbbrv In my case, every test case fails. Either returns null or undefined.

Comment: `useClass` is definitely enough to mock a class, so that should not be the cause of your problems. are there some compilation errors, is the component missing some other providers?

Comment: There are no other compilation errors.